# Azure cloud service: System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll requests old Newtonsoft.Json.dll -> role initialization fails

Tags: c#, nuget, azure-cloud-services, dll-dependency

I have pretty big solution with about 80 projects, running on the Azure cloud service server as Web role using WebAPI (v1). I have created new enhancement regarding content negotiation by implementing custom `JsonReader/Writer`. When I have tried use it by implementing custom `MediaTypeFormatter` based on the `BaseJsonMediaTypeFormatter` it fails - to be precise, it fails when published to the Azure. Locally emulated it works perfectly. Once published it fails as:

```
...
Role entrypoint could not be created: System.TypeLoadException: Unable to load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:
-- System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Newtonsoft.Json, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///E:/approot/bin
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = E:\approot\bin
Calling assembly : System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=5.2.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.
...
```

(Log captured from EventViewer->Application and Services log->Windows Azure).

Until I tried to use my custom `MediaTypeFormatter` everything worked correctly. I have searched internet and SO for some solution, and although the problem is not as rare as I thought none of the solution helped me. What have I tried:

- consolidated all versions of `Newtonsoft.Json` nugets in all referencing projects
- consolidated all versions of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` nuget
- removed all references to both mentioned libraries and replaced these references to dll by referencing the nuget instead
- upgraded both Nuget packages to the latest version (Json 12.0.3 and Formatting 5.2.7)  (I have even tried to use -reinstall parameter in `Update-Package` command)
- checked all `csproj` manually for referencing old `Newtonsoft.Json` version.
- Cleaned up solution, bin, obj folders, all cache files
- my `web.config` file contains (and have always contained) correct `bindingRedirect` for `Newtonsoft.Json`
- (and probably some other stuff, which I have already forgotten)

None of the solution worked and I still get this strange message.
My questions are:

- How is it possible, that `System.Net.Http.Formatting` library requires some specific version of Newtonsoft.Json when I explicitly say it should redirect to the 12th version? Is it because it happens during Webrole start (maybe because it doesn't respect web.config yet?)
- Why does it work on my computer, but does not deployed on the Azure cloud service? Does it somehow find and use also the old verison of Newtonsoft.Json lib on my local computer (and where, so I can try to remove it)?
- Is there any better way to debug this issue? Maybe log the sequence of loading referenced DLLs to get closer to the error? Or to duplicate the error on my local computer? At the moment it is very time consuming to deploy application, log on the remote desktop and check EventViewer on cloud service...

Any hint to find the issue will be appreciated.

Comment: 99.9% your deployed service has version of Newtonsoft.Json that is neither 6 nor 12.0.3... Adding reference to Newtonsoft NuGet to *all* project is likely the cure...

Comment: Just tried - all projects now references Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3 Nuget, deployed it, but it still says the same error :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to the solution with your web.config assembly binding.  However, the error message says "Unable to load the **role entry point**".  Your role entry point is your binary that hosts the OnStart/Run methods (ie. WebRole1.dll), which is different from your website content hosted in IIS.

To resolve this, open the .dll.config located in your project bin folder and use the same assembly binding information, then redeploy your service.

For more details see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/cie/cloud-services-roles-recycling-with-the-error-system-io-fileloadexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly.

Comment: That is exactly the missing piece. Thank you, it works. I just needed copy *.dll.config from bin folder next to the Web.config and include in project, and set CopyAlways to output folder.